# Failed to compile values file when running

Tags: android, android-studio, file, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am getting this error when running my app.

```
Failed to compile values file.
```

Why is this so ?
Why is this error occurring.
It does not occurs on other pc.
But occurring with mine.

I try to run my program but I have a Build: failed

This is log file

```
    1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2601-2654/? E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.auth.key.retrieval.service.START on com.google.android.gms
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1494-1494/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 497 ms
1687-1710/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2563-2732/? E/WakeLock: GCM_READ ** IS FORCE-RELEASED ON TIMEOUT **
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
5512-5512/? E/Finsky: [2] nae.a(5): Could not schedule hygiene tasks
    java.io.IOException: Inoperable file: canonical[/data/data/com.android.vending/files/finsky/shared/base_value_store.pb] freeSpace[7945261056] mode[33152]
        at amdq.d(PG:5)
        at amdq.e(PG:3)
        at amdq.c(PG:3)
        at alwg.b(PG:5)
        at alvz.a(PG:3)
        at anup.a(PG:2)
        at apfq.a(PG:4)
        at aphk.a(PG:2)
        at apgp.run(PG:3)
        at aphm.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at apft.run(PG:3)
        at aphc.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at aphd.run(PG:5)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at lez.run(PG:14)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.
        at ards.z(Unknown Source:5)
        at arda.a(PG:3)
        at arda.i(Unknown Source:0)
        at alxb.b(Unknown Source:8)
        at alwg.b(PG:3)
        at alvz.a(PG:3) 
        at anup.a(PG:2) 
        at apfq.a(PG:4) 
        at aphk.a(PG:2) 
        at apgp.run(PG:3) 
        at aphm.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at apft.run(PG:3) 
        at aphc.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at aphd.run(PG:5) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at lez.run(PG:14) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
1336-1336/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 753 ms
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2563-2730/? E/auto: Phenotype API error. Event # codx@ff0e282d, EventCode: 5 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    aust: 29501: Stale snapshot (change count changed - expected 2  but was 1)
        at autr.b(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):14)
        at autq.e(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):0)
        at auto.d(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):4)
        at auto.f(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at aedk.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):17)
        at bwhh.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at vzf.c(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):6)
        at vzf.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at wfc.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2563-2730/? E/AsyncOperation: operation=CommitToConfigurationOperationCall, opStatusCode=29501 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=Stale snapshot (change count changed - expected 2  but was 1), resolution=null}]
        at auto.d(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):6)
        at auto.f(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at aedk.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):17)
        at bwhh.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at vzf.c(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):6)
        at vzf.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at wfc.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
1493-1880/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(0xaa2a0f60:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
1493-1880/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xaa2a0f60:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1389-1389/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 157 ms
1389-1389/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 122 ms
4128-4128/? E/Dialer: VvmTaskExecutor - onStopJob
4128-4128/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.voicemail.impl.scheduling.TaskSchedulerJobService has leaked IntentReceiver bvs@9122e1a that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.android.voicemail.impl.scheduling.TaskSchedulerJobService has leaked IntentReceiver bvs@9122e1a that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1333)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1114)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1405)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1378)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1366)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:603)
        at bvs.<init>(PG:7)
        at com.android.voicemail.impl.ActivationTask.b(PG:130)
        at bvb.handleMessage(PG:7)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
1399-1399/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (2 threads) starved for 105 ms
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1399-1761/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (2 threads) starved for 165 ms
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
6056-6210/? E/GEL_DELAYED_EVENT_DEBUG: Failed delayed event dispatch, no dispatchers.
1687-1707/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.google.android.youtube
    PID: 6056
    Reason: executing service com.google.android.youtube/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
    Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
    CPU usage from 5191ms to 157ms ago (2021-07-24 11:28:03.854 to 2021-07-24 11:28:08.887):
      7.9% 6056/zygote: 4.1% user + 3.7% kernel / faults: 2166 minor 71 major
      6.7% 3270/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 3.7% user + 2.9% kernel / faults: 2643 minor 71 major
      5.1% 1687/system_server: 2.3% user + 2.7% kernel / faults: 102 minor 2 major
      4.1% 1432/kworker/u5:1: 0% user + 4.1% kernel
      2.7% 1418/kworker/u5:0: 0% user + 2.7% kernel
      2.7% 1433/kworker/u5:2: 0% user + 2.7% kernel
      2.3% 2563/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.3% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 69 minor 24 major
      1.7% 5721/com.google.android.apps.docs: 0.7% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 321 minor 8 major
      1.5% 5819/com.google.android.apps.maps: 0.3% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 328 minor 44 major
      1.1% 1397/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service: 0.1% user + 0.9% kernel
      0.3% 1384/adbd: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 129 minor
      0.3% 522/kswapd0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.3% 1473/jbd2/dm-0-8: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.3% 5216/com.google.android.gm: 0.3% user + 0% kernel
      0.1% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0% 12/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0.1% 778/kworker/u4:3: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 1334/logd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 1399/android.hardware.sensors@1.0-service: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 1420/dmcrypt_write: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0% 1434/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1489/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 25 minor 3 major
      0% 1492/android.hardware.gnss@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1570/ipv6proxy: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 major
      0% 2272/com.google.process.gapps: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
      0% 5712/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
    99% TOTAL: 6.6% user + 10% kernel + 81% iowait
    CPU usage from 839643ms to 839643ms ago (1970-01-01 05:00:00.000 to 1970-01-01 05:00:00.000) with 0% awake:
    0% TOTAL: 0% user + 0% kernel
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2563-2730/? E/auto: Phenotype API error. Event # codx@beda32fb, EventCode: 5 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    aust: 29501: Stale snapshot (change count changed - expected 5  but was 4)
        at autr.b(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):14)
        at autq.e(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):0)
        at auto.d(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):4)
        at auto.f(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at aedk.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):17)
        at bwhh.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at vzf.c(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):6)
        at vzf.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):8)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at wfc.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2563-2730/? E/AsyncOperation: operation=CommitToConfigurationOperationCall, opStatusCode=29501 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=Stale snapshot (change count changed - expected 5  but was 4), resolution=null}]
        at auto.d(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):6)
        at auto.f(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at aedk.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):17)
        at bwhh.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at vzf.c(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):6)
        at vzf.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):8)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at wfc.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2563-2732/? E/WakeLock: GCM_READ ** IS FORCE-RELEASED ON TIMEOUT **
2563-2742/? E/auto: Phenotype API error. Event # codx@ea6693a6, EventCode: 5 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    aust: 29500: Empty (package not registered?) or malformed snapshot token: 
        at autr.b(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):9)
        at autq.e(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):0)
        at auto.d(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):4)
        at auto.f(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at aedk.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):17)
        at bwhh.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at vzf.c(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):6)
        at vzf.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):8)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at wfc.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):0)
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=Empty (package not registered?) or malformed snapshot token: , resolution=null}]
        at auto.d(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):6)
        at auto.f(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at aedk.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):17)
        at bwhh.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):2)
        at vzf.c(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):6)
        at vzf.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):8)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at wfc.run(:com.google.android.gms@212418022@21.24.18 (040700-383468479):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
3270-3281/? E/A: Failed to commit experiments after account switch
    com.google.android.libraries.phenotype.client.a.e: 29500: 29500: Empty (package not registered?) or malformed snapshot token: 
        at com.google.android.libraries.phenotype.client.a.g.apply(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.google.common.w.a.a.d(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.common.w.a.c.run(SourceFile:11)
        at com.google.common.w.a.az.execute(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.common.w.a.d.i(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.common.w.a.d.m(SourceFile:11)
        at com.google.common.w.a.d.p(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.android.libraries.s.b.a(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.k.n.run(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.common.w.a.az.execute(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.k.o.b(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.k.ad.b(SourceFile:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.k.aj.v(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.dg.b(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.r.a(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.a.a.dispatchTransaction(SourceFile:31)
        at com.google.android.a.b.onTransact(SourceFile:2)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.n: 29500: Empty (package not registered?) or malformed snapshot token: 
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.dg.b(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.r.a(SourceFile:1) 
        at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.a.a.dispatchTransaction(SourceFile:31) 
        at com.google.android.a.b.onTransact(SourceFile:2) 
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674) 
1687-1710/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1834-6280/? E/PhenotypeModule: PhenotypeModule.handlePhenotypeConfigurationUpdates():249 Get empty configurations.
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
3018-6336/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2601-2654/? E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.auth.key.retrieval.service.START on com.google.android.gms
2563-2730/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
1400-1400/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 583 ms
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1805/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=28, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1805/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=27, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND] ]
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2601-6540/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2563-6541/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
5512-5588/? E/PlayCommon: [345] amlh.k(134): Failed to connect to server for server timestamp: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to play.googleapis.com/2a00:1450:4018:809::200a (port 443) from /fec0::5176:54cf:7330:76b9 (port 58130) after 40000ms
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1710/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
5512-5588/? E/PlayCommon: [345] amlh.k(173): Failed to connect to server for log upload.
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2601-6556/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2563-6557/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1710/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1805/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=30, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
3018-6565/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2601-2624/? E/SQLiteLog: (5) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE] database is locked
1834-6607/? E/PhenotypeModule: PhenotypeModule.handlePhenotypeConfigurationUpdates():249 Get empty configurations.
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
3270-3270/? E/A: Task 53 failed or timed out. Client 14383239198968074 disconnecting from SearchService!
    java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
        at com.google.common.w.a.d.s(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.common.w.a.d.get(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.common.w.a.dv.a(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.common.w.a.cb.q(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.common.w.a.bv.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.aq.run(SourceFile:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
3270-3356/? E/GcmBroadcastReceiver: processGenericClientEventInBackground failed
    java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
        at com.google.common.w.a.d.s(SourceFile:3)
        at com.google.common.w.a.d.get(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.common.w.a.dv.a(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.common.w.a.cb.q(SourceFile:2)
        at com.google.common.w.a.bv.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bt.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.c.a.bw.run(SourceFile:1)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.aa.run(SourceFile:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.m.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.libraries.g.c.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2601-6616/? E/Volley: [471] NetworkUtility.b: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/cryptauth/v1/deviceSync/getmydevices
2601-6601/? E/Authzen: [ProximitySyncManager] Failed to sync data with server for account: <ELLIDED:465420758>.
5512-5588/? E/PlayCommon: [345] amlh.k(134): Failed to connect to server for server timestamp: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to play.googleapis.com/2a00:1450:4018:803::200a (port 443) from /fec0::5176:54cf:7330:76b9 (port 53529) after 40000ms
1687-1710/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
1687-1707/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
1687-1706/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
6587-6677/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
6587-6677/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
6587-6677/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
6587-6677/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
3018-3029/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
3018-3029/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
3018-3029/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
3018-3029/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
3018-3029/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
```

Why is this error occurring.
It does not occurs on other pc.
But occurring with mine.

I try to run my program but I have a Build: failed

Comment: please attach catlogs

Comment: kindly check now